# Show/hide multiple KML on google maps in a certain radius with geolocation

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I was wondering if I could get some help on thinking how to tackle my problem.

I want to have the user's location by using geolocation and show this on a map. I have 5 different KML files, which I want to display on the map with markers if they are in a radius of 1 km of the user's position. When clicking on these markers, it should show information which is also present in the KML file (the title of the adress). Next to that, I want to have 6 buttons below the map which can toggle between these KML files (All KML files, Only KML 1, Only KML 2 etc.).

This area is very new for me, I've been combining multiple scripts but at the moment it's becoming a mess and I'm confused.

This is what I have:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
<script>

var infowindow;
var map;
var src = 'XX';

function initialize() {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 16,
keyboardShortcuts : false, 
mapTypeControl : false, 
mapMaker : false, 
overviewMapControl : false, 
panControl : false, 
rotateControl : false, 
scaleControl : false, 
scrollwheel : false, 
streetViewControl : false,
zoomControl : false 
  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

geocoder.geocode({'latLng': pos}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                //Check result 0

                var result = results[0];
                //look for locality tag and administrative_area_level_1
                var city = "";
                var state = "";
                for(var i=0, len=result.address_components.length; i<len; i++) {
                    var ac = result.address_components[i];
                    if(ac.types.indexOf("locality") >= 0) city = ac.long_name;
                    if(ac.types.indexOf("administrative_area_level_1") >= 0) state = ac.long_name;
                }
                //only report if we got Good Stuff
                if(city != '' && state != '') {
                    var $z = jQuery.noConflict();
                    $z("#result").html(""+city+"");
                }
            } 
        });


    loadKmlLayer(src, map);

    var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pos,
      map: map,
      content: 'Your location'
  });


      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
  });

 google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) {
    var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
    var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
    testimonial.innerHTML = content;
  });
}


  function createMarker(name, latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: name});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
  }

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    alert('Please enable GPS services!');
    var content = 'Please enable GPS services!';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };


  map.setCenter(options.position);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    </script>
```

So to summarize:

1. Initialize and create the map
2. I have read that calculating distance with google maps API is limited to 100 addresses per 10 seconds...I want to calculate 7000 adressess, can I also do this with PHP and ajax? I have a PHP script which outputs the distance if given the lat/long values.
3. Add the markers to the map which are within the radius and make it possible to toggle between them using jquery .show/.hide? How do I make this javascript dynamic?
4. I need to center the map on the users location, currently its not working anymore and I don't know why.
5. If onclick=initialize() start again at 1.

Is this thinking OK? How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: Optionally, radius doesn't have to be included. If all markers are shown it's OK as long as the location of the user is included as a marker and toggling is possible! I just found this example http://www.bramvandenbulcke.be/en/content/google-map-layer-toggle. Could be useful for others as well, I will look into this. If anyone has other thoughts, please let me know!